# Partition by Quarterly Years

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I add another column that would partition them quarterly (Jan-March, April-June, June-Sep) and then add another counter to keep track of the quarterly and define that Q1 2011 is not the same as Q1 2012. Essentially how would I add the Quarters and Tracker Column. I have looked at ROW_NUMBER(), NTILE functions but not sure how to combine them with months.

```
--- Period --- Quarters---Tracker
2012-05-06       2          1
2012-05-20       2          1          
2012-06-03       2          1
2012-07-01       3          2
2012-08-12       3          2
2012-08-26       3          2
2012-09-09       3          2
2012-10-07       4          3
2012-10-21       4          3
2012-11-04       4          3
2012-11-18       4          3
2012-12-02       4          3
2012-12-16       4          3
2012-12-30       4          3 
2013-01-13       1          4
2013-01-27       1          4
```

REALLY STUCK!

Comment: Is the column Quarters already available?

Comment: no thats just an example of how it should be only the date column is available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the quarter `CASE` logic in the table definition, but you could also put it in the query so you don't have to modify your table.

```
Create  Table Blah 
(
        SampleDate Date Default(Convert(Date,Getdate())),
        Quarters As (   Case
                        When    Month(SampleDate) Between 1 And 3 Then 1
                        When    Month(SampleDate) Between 4 And 6 Then 2
                        When    Month(SampleDate) Between 7 And 9 Then 3
                        Else    4 End)
)

Insert  Blah (SampleDate)
Select  '2012-05-06'
Union   All
Select  '2012-05-20'
Union   All
Select  '2012-06-03'
Union   All
Select  '2012-07-01'
Union   All
Select  '2012-08-12'
Union   All
Select  '2012-09-09'
Union   All
Select  '2012-10-07'
Union   All
Select  '2012-11-04'
Union   All
Select  '2012-12-16'
Union   All
Select  '2013-01-13'
Union   All
Select  '2013-01-27'

Select  *, 
        Dense_Rank() Over (Order By Year(SampleDate),Quarters) As Tracker
From    Blah
```

Comment: the following is the error that I get when I try running this:

Comment: The following is the error that I get when I try running this:

Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: Try now, I updated the insert to specifically into the SampleDate column

Answer (score 0):

So you want a simple column to represent your actual quarter?
2012-Q1, 2011-Q1, 2010-Q1 that you would like to use SQL Partitions on? Or you want 2 columns? One to be partitioned on, and another one to actually indicate the year?

Thinking about it, do you need a counter? Couldn't you just set up the other column to be the year?

so you would have 2 columns. One indicating the quarter, and the other the year

```
quarter year
1       2011
1       2012
1       2010
```

Comment: Well Later on I'll have an additional column with data (numbers) and will be average based on 2012-Q1, 2011-Q1 and so forth...so which approach would you recommend having what I suggested or is there another approach that I can take??

Comment: If you have it available (SQL Server Standard doesn't), use partitions. They're a bit more work, but performance wise, they're much better. Plus, it's much easier to clean data out of them. You can simply drop a partition, barely locking the table, instead of DELETE * FROM table1 WHERE quarter=1 AND year=2012. The latter would lock your table while deleting the rows.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms345146(v=SQL.90).aspx